# Exponential growth and implications (yet again)

Tags: integration, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I quote from [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868705/implication-of-exponential-growth-how-is-it-deduced):

> Let $L$ be a differentiable function defined on $\mathbb{R}\times\Omega$ with $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. I will say it has *exponential growth* if for all $O\subset\subset\Omega$ open there exists a constant $C(O)$ such that:
>
> $$|\nabla_\xi L(x,\xi)|\leq C(O)L(x,\xi),$$
>
> for all $\xi\in O$. A photocopy I was given from a book I can't identify uses this condition to deduce the following:
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt}L(x,a+tb)=\langle\nabla_\xi L(x,a+tb),b\rangle\leq c|b|L(x,a),$$
>
> and I understand that, and then:
>
> $$L(x,a+b)\leq L(x,a)e^{c|b|}.$$
>
> How is this last inequality deduced from the previous one?

Trouble is, the second displayed equation is mistyped. What I should have written, i.e. what I *can* derive from the exponential growth condition, is:

$$\frac{d}{dt}L(x,a+tb)=\langle\nabla_\xi L(x,a+tb),b\rangle\leq c|b|L(x,a+tb),$$

and if I integrate this from 0 to 1, as the answer to the previous question suggested, I get:

$$L(x,a+b)-L(x,a)\leq\int_0^1c|b|L(x,a+tb)dt,$$

which I cannot see how to turn into the last displayed equation in the quoted text. So I am asking:

> Can I either derive the mistyped inequality from the exponential growth, or the final displayed equation from the correctly typed version of the mistyped inequality? And in either case, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last inequality is a simple application of Gronwall's inequality. But we will prove it directly.

Let us use the notation
\begin{align}
f(t) = L(x, a+tb)
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
f'(t) \leq c|b|f(t).
\end{align}
Observe by the method of integrating factors, we have
\begin{align}
f'(t)-c|b| f(t) \leq 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{d}{dt}[e^{-b|c|t}f(t)] \leq 0
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
e^{-b|c|t}f(t)-e^{-b|c|t_0}f(t_0)= \int^t_{t_0} \frac{d}{ds}[e^{-b|c|s}f(s)]\ ds \leq 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ e^{-b|c|t}f(t) \leq e^{-c|b|t_0}f(t_0)= f(0).
\end{align}
Hence we have the desired inequality
\begin{align}
f(t) \leq f(0)e^{b|c|t} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ L(x, a+tb) \leq L(x, a)e^{b|c|t}.
\end{align}
Now plug in $t=1$.

Comment: I guess you implicitly plugged in $t_0=0$ at the end of thebnext-to-last display. Otherwise I cannot explain the exponential factor disappearing and $t_0$ turning to $0$.

Comment: Sorry. Bad habit of mine.